# validity reduction between FOL fragments

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

Let $\Sigma_1=\langle R^2,P^1,=\rangle$ a dictionary with $R$ a binary relation, $P$ an unary relation and equality.

Let $\Sigma_2=\langle c,f^1,=\rangle$ a dictionary with $c$ a constant, $f$ an unary function and equality.

**Prove or Disprove**: There exists an algorithm that given a formula $\varphi$ over the alphabet $\Sigma_2$ outputs a formula $\psi$ over the alphabet $\Sigma_1$ such that $\varphi$ is valid if and only if $\psi$ is valid.

I know that in monadic logic validity is decidable since satisfiability is decidable but $\Sigma_2$ is not monadic as it contains a binary relation.

I tried to prove that satisfiability in $\Sigma_1$ is decidable but it dosen't seem that way.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such an algorithm. The main idea is that we can simulate the constant symbol $c$ with the unary relation $P$, by asserting that there is a unique element satisfying $P$, and we can simulate the function symbol $f$ with the binary relation $R$, by asserting that $R$ is the graph of a function.

So we turn the $\Sigma_2$-formula $\varphi$ into a $\Sigma_1$-formula of the following form:

$$((\exists^! x\, P(x)) \land (\forall x\, \exists^! y\, R(x,y)) \rightarrow \hat{\varphi},$$
where $\exists^!x$ means "there exists a unique $x$" and $\hat{\varphi}$ is  a formula obtained by "replacing all instances of $c$ and $f$ in $\varphi$ with $P$ and $R$."

I put the last part in quotes there for a reason: we have to think a bit about how to construct $\hat{\varphi}$. The problem is that $\Sigma_2$-formulas can have nested terms, which we have to unravel. For example, suppose $\varphi$ is the formula $$f(c) = f(f(x)).$$

This is equivalent to the unnested formula $$\exists z_1\, (c = z_1 \land \exists z_2\, (f(z_1) = z_2 \land (\exists z_3\, f(x) = z_3 \land \exists z_4\, (f(z_3) = z_4 \land z_2 = z_4)))).$$

The point is that $c$ only appears in subformulas of the form $c = z$ for $z$ a variable, equivalent to $P(z)$. And $f$ only appears in subformulas of the form $f(z) = w$ for $z$ and $w$ variables, equivalent to $R(z,w)$.

Then we can take $\hat{\varphi}$ to be $$\exists z_1\, (P(z_1) \land \exists z_2\, (R(z_1,z_2) \land (\exists z_3\, R(x,z_3) \land \exists z_4\, (R(z_3,z_4) \land z_2 = z_4))))$$

I'll leave it to you to fill in the details in the general case.

---

P.S. This idea of simulating constant and function symbols by relation symbols allows us to safely assume, in many contexts in model theory, that we're working with a purely relational language. This assumption isn't always safe, though: whether we have function symbols in the language matters if we're thinking about substructures (in a relational language, any subset is a substructure) or quantifier elimination (the translation from a general language to a relational language involves adding quantifiers).

P.P.S. $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ have [standard meanings in logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), so it's probably better to use other notation for your languages/dictionaries! Also, the collection of all formulas in the language $\Sigma_1$ is just full first-order logic in the language $\Sigma_1$. It's not called a "fragment" - except in the trivial sense that it's the maximal fragment (the full logic).

Comment: @TrueTopologist Oops, I just noticed that you asked about validity, not satisfiability. So my original formula was wrong (it should be $(\dots)\rightarrow \hat{\varphi}$, not $(\ldots)\land \hat{\varphi}$). That is, we want to say "if $P$ picks out a constant and $R$ defines a function, then $\hat{\varphi}$ is true".

Comment: Yes I figured that out, thank you.